# Unexpected results when binding in nested foreach using Breeze.js

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I'm using Knockout.js 2.2.1 and Breeze 1.3.5 to retrieve and display some data but the results are way off. The data comes from a self referencing table. As far as I can tell Knockout seems to think that the *Children* property of each item should return the entire array and not the actual children of item. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**: I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StrandedPirate/Wu9LA/) and I get the expected results but it doesn't use breeze.js. So perhaps this is a breeze.js issue? Something of note in the fiddle is that *Children* and *Name* are both referenced without parenthesis whereas in my full blown application breeze.js seems to be converting them to the proper observables* and requiring parenthesis for the *Name*.

Current result:

```
Apparel
- Apparel
Art
- Art
Books
- Books
Movies
- Movies
test
- test
Blu-ray
- Blu-ray
DVD
- DVD
Animation
- Animation
Accessories
- Accessories
```

Expected result:

```
Apparel
- Accessories
Art
- Animation
Books
Movies
- Blu-ray
- DVD
test
```

VM:

```
var vm = {
    categories: ko.observableArray()
};
```

Knockout.js markup:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: categories">
    <div data-bind="text: Name"></div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: Children">
        <div data-bind="text: ' - ' + Name()"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Breeze code:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Category")
    .orderBy("ParentCategoryId, Name")
    .expand("Children");

_entityManager
    .executeQuery(query)
    .then(function (data) {
        vm.categories.removeAll();
        console.log("here: " + data.results.length); -- produces 9
        data.results.forEach(function (item) {
            vm.categories.push(item);
        });
    })
    .fail(function (error) { console.log("Error: " + error); });
```

Breeze query results:

```
[ { "$id" : "1",
    "$type" : "SR.Data.Models.Domain.Category, SR.Data",
    "CategoryId" : 5,
    "Children" : [ { "$id" : "2",
          "$type" : "SR.Data.Models.Domain.Category, SR.Data",
          "CategoryId" : 6,
          "Children" : [  ],
          "CreatedOn" : "2013-05-31T11:29:11.860",
          "Description" : "Accessories",
          "IsDeleted" : false,
          "IsPublished" : true,
          "Name" : "Accessories",
          "ParentCategory" : { "$ref" : "1" },
          "ParentCategoryId" : 5
        } ],
    "CreatedOn" : "2013-05-31T11:28:37.677",
    "Description" : "Apperal",
    "IsDeleted" : false,
    "IsPublished" : true,
    "Name" : "Apparel"
  },
  { "$id" : "3",
    "$type" : "SR.Data.Models.Domain.Category, SR.Data",
    "CategoryId" : 3,
    "Children" : [ { "$id" : "4",
          "$type" : "SR.Data.Models.Domain.Category, SR.Data",
          "CategoryId" : 4,
          "Children" : [  ],
          "CreatedOn" : "2013-05-31T11:25:46.333",
          "Description" : "Animation",
          "IsDeleted" : false,
          "IsPublished" : true,
          "Name" : "Animation",
          "ParentCategory" : { "$ref" : "3" },
          "ParentCategoryId" : 3
        } ],
    "CreatedOn" : "2013-05-31T11:25:30.250",
    "Description" : "Art",
    "IsDeleted" : false,
    "IsPublished" : true,
    "Name" : "Art"
  },
  { "$id" : "5",
    "$type" : "SR.Data.Models.Domain.Category, SR.Data",
    "CategoryId" : 1,
    "Children" : [  ],
    "CreatedOn" : "2013-05-13T17:14:15.880",
    "Description" : "Books",
    "IsDeleted" : false,
    "IsPublished" : true,
    "Name" : "Books"
  },
  { "$id" : "6",
    "$type" : "SR.Data.Models.Domain.Category, SR.Data",
    "CategoryId" : 2,
    "Children" : [ { "$id" : "7",
          "$type" : "SR.Data.Models.Domain.Category, SR.Data",
          "CategoryId" : 7,
          "Children" : [  ],
          "CreatedOn" : "2013-05-31T11:31:05.710",
          "Description" : "Blu-ray",
          "IsDeleted" : false,
          "IsPublished" : true,
          "Name" : "Blu-ray",
          "ParentCategory" : { "$ref" : "6" },
          "ParentCategoryId" : 2
        },
        { "$id" : "8",
          "$type" : "SR.Data.Models.Domain.Category, SR.Data",
          "CategoryId" : 8,
          "Children" : [  ],
          "CreatedOn" : "2013-05-31T11:31:15.000",
          "Description" : "DVD",
          "IsDeleted" : false,
          "IsPublished" : true,
          "Name" : "DVD",
          "ParentCategory" : { "$ref" : "6" },
          "ParentCategoryId" : 2
        }
      ],
    "CreatedOn" : "2013-05-14T12:13:36.570",
    "Description" : "DVD's & Blu-ray",
    "IsDeleted" : false,
    "IsPublished" : true,
    "Name" : "Movies"
  },
  { "$id" : "9",
    "$type" : "SR.Data.Models.Domain.Category, SR.Data",
    "CategoryId" : 11,
    "Children" : [  ],
    "CreatedOn" : "2013-06-03T15:32:50.023",
    "Description" : "test",
    "IsDeleted" : false,
    "IsPublished" : true,
    "Name" : "test"
  },
  { "$ref" : "7" },
  { "$ref" : "8" },
  { "$ref" : "4" },
  { "$ref" : "2" }
]
```

Category entity:

```
public class Category
{
    public Category() { }

    public virtual int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual int? PictureId { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsPublished { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }

    public virtual Picture Picture { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Category mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasKey(a => a.CategoryId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasOptional(x => x.Picture).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.PictureId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasOptional(x => x.ParentCategory).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentCategoryId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasMany(x => x.Children).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentCategoryId);
```

Category table:

[image: Category table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out finally! My mapping setup of the entity was wrong. Just when I thought I couldn't hate the people that made this convoluted api any more, they prove me wrong.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasOptional(x => x.ParentCategory).WithMany(x => x.ChildrenElements).HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentCategoryId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell. Looks basically right .. **except for a markup error** (below). The JSON is nice to have but I can't tell what you actually have for Category entities after the query completes.

Before we take a next step, what happens when you fix the markup?

#### Markup mistake

You don't want the parentheses after "Name" in the children template. It should be

```
<div data-bind="text: ' - ' + Name"></div> <!-- NO PARENS AFTER NAME -->
```

as it is in your Fiddle.

#### Cleaner success callback

While you're here, you might consider this alternative syntax which simply replaces the inner array with the query results array; no iteration needed.

```
.then(function (data) {
        vm.categories(data.results);
        console.log("here: " + data.results.length); -- produces 9
        });
    })
```

Comment: Without the parenthesis I get `- function ko.dependentObservable(){...}` for each child. I used the non-iteration array setter you suggested and I added the entity information to the original post at the bottom. Does my setup of the _Children_ navigation property look correct?